# How to send Intent with extras to Library Project Activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have created a library project with one activity. I have given reference of this library project to my Main Project. I am trying to call Activity of Library Project with some extras through intent. But I am getting null pointer exception while retrieving getIntent.getExtras in Library Project. Any idea how to do this?

I am starting activity of Library Project like below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity,com.***.***.LibActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("key", "abcds");
    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

And I am trying to retrieve the key in LibActivity (Which is in library project) like below:

getIntent().getExtras().getString("key") -->Throwing null pointer exception at this line

I have added this activity to my Main Projects manifest.

Comment: Post your code and logcat..

Comment: Do you have the library activity listed in the manifest of your main project?

Comment: I am starting activity of Library Project like below:


  Intent intent = new Intent(activity,com.***.***.LibActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("key", "abcds");
  activity.startActivity(intent);
 
And I am trying to retrieve the key in LibActivity (Which is in library project) like below:

getIntent().getExtras().getString("key") -->Throwing null pointer exception at this line

I have added this activity to my Main Projects manifest.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass this on your main project

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("shopId", shopId);
this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

And in your Library activity You have to pass just this

```
String intentdata = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("shopId");
```

Then boom your work is done!