# How to send intent data from main project to library project in android?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have been trying to send data from my main project to my library project.
My library project is defined in main project so no problem of adding dependency of lib project.one more thread I have found similar to my problem but no luck so far...[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308223/how-to-send-intent-with-extras-to-library-project-activity)

**GetUserprofile** is the main project's activity and **LockscreenActivity** is library project's activity.

I have written code on the main project side

```
Intent myIntent = null;
    try {
        myIntent = new Intent(GetUserprofile.this,LockscreenActivity.class);

       myIntent.putExtra("examiddetails",exam_id);

        startActivity(myIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I am getting the data which is examiddetails on the library project by using below code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();    
    try{
        if(intent != null){
            String Examid = intent.getStringExtra("examiddetails");
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("getdataFromService exception"+e.toString());
    }
```

I am **getting null value of Examid String** on the library project.

Comment: Please check the value of exam_id. What is the signature of the variable ?

Comment: Its String so that's not a problem

Answer (score 0):

Create Intent From your application

```
Intent myIntent= new Intent(this,YourActivity.class)
myIntent.putExtra("data", "value");
```

Get the Intent From Library

```
string intentdata = ((Activity)getContext()).getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
```

Comment: No Luck Still I am getting null

Comment: @Brat can you check whether the activity is correct in library project.  
 Activity intentdata = ((Activity)getContext()); the activity should be same as your passing activity

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean send data to another activity?
I had made same before.

MainProject class

```
Intent intent= new intent(getApplication(), LockscreenActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("examiddetails",exam_id);
startActivity(intent);
```

LockscreenActivity class

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String ExamIdDetails = bundle.getString("examiddetails");
```

Comment: I am sending data to library project not into the same project...i guess this works fine when you have two activity in the main project...but i have main project and library project and i have to send data from main project to library project via intent or any other way would be fine